# How can I delete this apparently undeletable/invincible 0 byte desktop icon in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I’m running Windows 7 and I have an icon on my desktop called `_USAJ-PRDDSFS1_Candidate_6334_13727_7FF2294F-9C5D-462F-818D-B3903872BAF8.doc`

When I try to remove it I get the message:

> Could not find this item. Verfy the items location and try again.

This thing has been pestering me since 2012 and *will not* go away. Can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Command Prompt as Administrator
2. `cd` to target directory
3. use `dir /a /x /p`
4. in the third column, look for the file name. Then find its name in column two.
5. use `del [filename found in step 4]`

Comment: If I finish elaborating, I'll post my answer in the proper question.